Is there a module $M$ over a ring $R$ with unity such that $M = Rx$ and $M = Ry + Rz$ but $Ry \lneq M$ and $Rz \lneq M$, where $x, y, z \in M$?
Let $R$ be a ring with unity.
Is there a module $M$ over $R$ such that $M = Rx$ and $M = Ry + Rz$ but $Ry \neq M$ and $Rz \neq M$, where $x, y, z \in M$? In other words, $Ry$ and $Rz$ are proper submodules of $M$, i.e., $Ry \lneq M$ and $Rz \lneq M$.
If $R$ is a field, the above situation does not occur. What about general rings, such as integral domains?

I get your point. Thank you.

@azif00 Please move your solution out of the comments and into the solutions...

Take $M=R=\Bbb Z$, $x=1$, $y=2$ and $z=3$.
